# JavaScript date.format is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

I am using this piece of code to get string representing date `yyyy-mm-dd` from a hidden field and then format it as needed:

```
var date_string = $('#end-date').val();
var splitDate = date_string.split("-");
var end_date = new Date(splitDate[0], splitDate[1] - 1, splitDate[2]);
end_date.format("dddd, mmmm dS, yyyy")
```

But it throws an error:

```
end_date.format is not a function
```

Why does it happen and how to solve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That is because `.format` is not a native JavaScript function on `Date.prototype`.

You need to add a lib like this one: http://jacwright.com/projects/javascript/date_format/

I personally use http://momentjs.com/ to manage dates in JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because [`Date.prototype.format` just does not exist](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.5) (I am wondering why you think it does).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript) about solutions how to format dates.